# The program is running fine during the debuging. But when i am running the program getting this error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    public void VerfiyPcsAccount() throws Exception
        {
            String expectedId="111109531";
            BasePage Baseobj=new BasePage();
            Baseobj.LoginAdmin3();
            driver.switchTo().frame("bottom");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
custinfoprimusclick(admin.getProperty("admin_custinfoprimuslink"));
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame("bottom");
            driver.findElement(By.name("w_custno")).sendKeys("111109531");
            click(admin.getProperty("admin_findclick"));
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            driver.switchTo().frame("bottom");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='globalnav']/tbody/tr[1]/td/a[5]")).click();
            String actualId=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Primus DHP Portal")).click();
            Thread.sleep(30000);
```

I have debug the application its execute fine.When i am running the application i got the error:: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.7.236900,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.13 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.49.0', revision: '365eeb4', time: '2016-01-13 18:33:29'
System info: host: 'GGNLAP-NSINGH', ip: '10.10.251.198', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[contains(text(),'Customer Info - Primus')]}

Comment: use wait function and not sleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is resolve i have increase the time for 2second.
Its working fine.
try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            custinfoprimusclick(admin.getProperty("admin_custinfoprimuslink"));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
Thanks
```